# How do I deal with `NA` in a numeric vector when they provide information?

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I have a dataframe with variables `days to first booking` and `booked`.

Booked is boolean and indicates whether a room has been booked.

Days to first booking will show the number of days from today until the first booking, except in cases where there are no bookings in which case it is `NA`.

I want to use those variables as part of a logistic regression, but I don't know how to deal with the `NA`. I don't want to get rid of the numeric altogether because it provides valuable information.

Comment: Why not just have a logistic regression for booked and another regression for days to first booking for observations where booked=1?  But if it's really important to include both variables in a single model, you could potentially use a hazard model.

Comment: I ended up replacing the variable with a different variable. Instead of using days to first booking, I did number of bookings. It doesn't get at quite the same information, but it's close enough for my purposes.